# Avoid race condition ?. operator

Tags: c#, events, delegates, race-condition

Does the `?.` operator that can be used to invoke a delegate or event avoid race conditions?

Eg. avoid race-condition manually:

```
//The event-invoking method that derived classes can override.
        protected virtual void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
            // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
            // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
            EventHandler<ShapeEventArgs> handler = ShapeChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
```

source: [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes)

Comment: Yes. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

> Another use for the null-condition member access is invoking delegates
> in a thread-safe way with much less code.
>
> ...
>
> The new way is thread-safe because the compiler generates code to
> evaluate PropertyChanged one time only

[MSDN Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Comment: thx btw the example from msdn also works without overriding the virtual method. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @GernotAtStackoverflow what virtual method are you referring to?

Comment: protected virtual void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e)

Comment: sry I got it... forget that